# Adding Azure Blob Storage on EPiServer (v 11.20.14) Site causes 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, episerver

First of all - I've tried all the solutions given in the other threads regarding this problem. Nothing has so far solved my issue.

Our client have been running a fileshare as the default blob provider, there's been some issues with getting that to fully work so they've been doing some work around. They wish to move it to Azure Storage. We've set up a storage account and container, all according to the guides.

I managed to copy all the blobs using AzCopy to the container I want to use. But as soon as I introduce this to my web.config, it crashes and gives me a 400 response.

```
<blob defaultProvider="azureblobs">
  <providers>
    <add name="azureblobs" type="EPiServer.Azure.Blobs.AzureBlobProvider,EPiServer.Azure" connectionStringName="EPiServerAzureBlobs" container="mycontainer" />
  </providers>
</blob>

<add name="EPiServerAzureBlobs" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxxxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"/>
```

The exception thrown is as follows:

```
One or more errors occurred.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at EPiServer.Framework.FrameworkInitialization.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<InitializeBlobProviders>b__0(Object o, EventArgs e)

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at EPiServer.Azure.Blobs.DefaultAzureBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExist()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 677
```

We are running on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and EPiServer.CMS v.11.20.14 which means some of the newer packages for Azure won't work, so I'm currently using EPiServer.Azure v.9.4.4 and WindowsAzure.Storage 8.5.0. I know a split has been made for this package, but installing the seperate ones did not fix the problem. Any clues to what might be causing this? Thank you!

Comment: Is that locally or through Jenkins?

Comment: @TedNyberg This is locally.

Comment: (Assuming you can use this connection string to connect to storage, like via azure storage explorer?) basically we need more info. as this is locally - you can for example try adding proxy like Fiddler, make sure your local site instance is using that, and see what really happens in the fiddler - what HTTPS requests being sent, and what Azure responds. It can be connection string issue, container issue etc. OR you can just create simple console app with the same packages and the same connection string, and try doing simple steps like open container - create blob etc

Comment: @Lanorkin I took it through Fiddler, and now I'm even more confused, cause as soon as I did the site launched. But still not working outside of it. Will dig into that more tomorrow.

Comment: Could you please share your code which you are trying.

Comment: I updated my question with some more info and how I got it to work. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what caused the problem to begin with, but I wanted to share what was the solution for me.

So updating the targeted framwork to 4.6.2 made it possible to update some of the packages, including EPiServer.Azure to 10.0.1. I was also able to dive a bit deeper into the problem and found an inner exception: "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive)" on page load. So adding this to my webconfig put the site back up:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

For the blobs to work I made a new copy from my local directory to my container using AzCopy, putting them directly under the container and not inside a sub-directory. After that I ran the BlobConverter-job from the EPiCode.BlobConverter nuget and it's finally running as I wanted.